# Returning value from subscription typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-observables

How would i return success from `Save()` method.

```
public SaveItem() {
 if(save()){ // The goal is to use save method like this
  // Close pop up;
}

public SaveAndNew() {
 if(save()){  // The goal is to use save method like this
  // Create new item;
}


private save() {
 let issuccess = false;

 this.myservice.AddParty(newUserObject)
  .subscribe(data => {   
    if (data['status'].toString() === '1') {
      return issuccess = false;
    } else {
      return issuccess = true;
    }
  },
    (er) => {

      return issuccess = false;
    });
}
```

- If i have `save(): boolean` it will throw error that `Must return a value` if return `issuccess` outside the subscribe it will always return a false value.

**How would i await the save function and return a specific value based on response ?**

*I have read about callbacks and its seems to be not elegant, Is there any elegant way to do this*

[callbacks-vs-promises-vs-rxjs-vs-async-awaits](https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/callbacks-vs-promises-vs-rxjs-vs-async-awaits/)

If its a C# i would do this

```
var isSuccess = await SaveAsync(party);
```

Comment: you can convert to a promise..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can make your save method return an observable of boolean value

```
public SaveAndNew() {

this.save().subscribe(success =>
{
    if(success)
    {
      // Create new item;
    }
});

private save() : Observable<boolean> {

 return this.myservice
            .AddParty(newUserObject)
            .map(data=> data['status'].toString() === '1')
            .catch(err => Observable.of(false)); 
}
```

Comment: There is error saying that save ` 'Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '() => Observable<boolean>'`

Comment: I edited my post, it should be this.save() instead of this.save

Comment: its not because of it,

Comment: Its returning a promise not a observable

Comment: Sorry, what is returning a promise?

Comment: sorry i messed with 2 methods.

Comment: WHat's the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165474/discussion-between-eldho-and-david).

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
public SaveItem() {
 const isNew = false;
 save(isNew)
}

public SaveAndNew() {
 const isNew = true;
 save(isNew)
}


private save(isNew) {

 this.myservice.AddParty(newUserObject)
  .subscribe(data => {   
    if (data['status'].toString() === '1') {
      saveComplete(isNew);
    } else {
      saveFailed(isNew)
    }
  },
    (er) => {
      saveFailed(isNew)
    });
}

saveComplete(isNew) {
  // Check isNew as needed.
  // Close dialog or whatever
}

saveFailed(isNew) {
  // do whatever here
}
```

Or ... TypeScript now supports async/await ... so you could consider using them here. See this for more information: https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-observable-interop-with-promises-and-async-await-bebb05306875

Answer (score 1):

> In this case you can use  `promise` instead of `subscribe`. But while binding the data into html, then you should go with [**async pipe**](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

So, your service would be like

```
 AddParty(newUserObject) {
        return this.http.post(url)
            .toPromise().then(responce => <any[]>responce.json())
            .catch(error => {
                return error;
            });
    }
```

and retrieve that looks like

```
this.myservice.AddParty(newUserObject)
            .then(data => {
                if (data['status'].toString() === '1') {
                    return issuccess = false;
                } else {
                    return issuccess = true;
                }
            },
            (er) => {

                return issuccess = false;
            });
    }
```

Comment: Moving to promise is not an option for me , most of my code is with subscribe pattern. Thanks for the option

Answer (score 1):

try it like

```
public SaveItem() {
 if(save()){ // The goal is to use save method like this
  // Close pop up;
}

public SaveAndNew() {
 if(save()){  // The goal is to use save method like this
  // Create new item;
}


private async save() {
 let issuccess = false;

await  this.myservice.AddParty(newUserObject)
  .subscribe(data => {   
    if (data['status'].toString() === '1') {
      return issuccess = false;
    } else {
      return issuccess = true;
    }
  },
    (er) => {

      return issuccess = false;
    });
      return issuccess ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We have another action parameter in subscribe() after er action that will help you to return without using observable.

```
  public SaveItem() {
     if(save()){ // The goal is to use save method like this
      // Close pop up;
    }

    public SaveAndNew() {
     if(save()){  // The goal is to use save method like this
      // Create new item;
    }


    private save() {
     let issuccess = false;

     this.myservice.AddParty(newUserObject)
      .subscribe(data => {   
        if (data['status'].toString() === '1') {
          issuccess = false;
        } else {
          issuccess = true;
        }
      },
        (er) => {

          issuccess = false;
        },
     () => {return issuccess });
    }
```

**Subsribe 3 paramters**

```
subscribe(next?: (value: T) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void):
```

Comment: What is the operator using in it, do you have any doc n it